# How to deal with accidental input of a double when using .nextInt() in Java?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

So I am trying to deal with the possible exception of a user entering a double when my scanner is expecting integral input:

```
boolean go = true;
do {
        System.out.print("Please enter one grade from 0 - 100. To end input, enter a        
        negative integral value.\n");
    try {
            int myInt = scanner.nextInt();
            .
            .
            .
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Oops!! Please enter only integral numbers");
    }
while (go);
```

This works for non-numerical input (i.e. a letter), but not if I enter, say 3.14 or another ASCII symbol like -. In that case, the lines below repeat until I kill the program.

```
Please enter one grade from 0 - 100. To end input, enter a negative integral value.
Oops!! Please enter only integral numbers.
```

Any ideas? :D

Reply: I am using System.in, and java 6.

Comment: Can you be a little more precise than "my code explodes" ?

Comment: what do you mean as "explodes" ? Are you getting another exception?

Comment: If user enters a `double` at `scanner.nextInt();`, and `InputMismatchException` does indeed get thrown. Are you sure you aren't doing something else in your code? If not, what is the value that does get read, is it a rounded down version of the double that was entered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess, that when you say explodes, you mean that you are getting an infinite loop of

```
Oops!! Please enter only integral numbers
```

Try doing the following instead:

```
try {
  int myInt = scanner.nextInt();
  // …
}
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
  System.out.println("Oops!! Please enter only integral numbers");
  System.out.println(scanner.next() + " was not valid input.");
}
```

**Edit**: I see that my initial guess was right ;-)

The reason that this is happening is that when nextInt() fails, the internal pointer is not moved on, and so every time that you can nextInt again, it fails on the same token. So, you need to clear the token out first, which is what I am doing by printing out the text that is invalid input. This then causes a new token to be read from the input stream.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the code you posted above (using a System.in InputStream), and doubles cause an `InputMismatchException` as expected.  What input method are you using, and what version of Java?